# Reading row data from CSV file

Tags: python

I'm currently trying to create a program that reads a CSV file, more specifically row data (data in lines across)

**Sampledata.csv:**

```
['Time', 'Date', 'Color  ', 'Name']
['1pm', '01-01-99', 'blue', 'jack']
['2pm', '02-02-99', 'green', 'kevin']
['3pm', '03-03-99', 'yellow', 'phil']
['4pm', '04-04-99', 'white', 'alice']
['5pm', '05-05-99', 'black', 'bob']
```

Here is my code:

```
import csv  
with open('Sampledata.csv', 'r') as csvfile :
      regnumber = input("What is your regnumber?")
      reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
for row in reader:
     print(row) # here lies the problem(python is reading columnal data (data going down) instead of row(lines across) data#
```

The problem is in reading the columns (data going down). Python reads the columns instead.

Output:

```
Date
01-01-99
02-02-99
03-03-99
04-04-99
05-05-99
```

Comment: So is there any questions?

Comment: Your code (even with the correct indentation) and the output doesn't match. When I run it, I get the correct output, namely the data of each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the one you're looking for?

```
import csv  #ignore my stupidity with the indentation and spaces#
with open('Sampledata.csv', 'r') as csvfile :
    regnumber = raw_input("Enter the time:")
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        if(row[0]==regnumber):
            print ', '.join(row)
        else:
            continue
```

The above code print values from csv file row by row.

Comment: Sree Harissh it does work but it only shows columnal data (data from each column) I wanted row data (lines across )

Comment: @albinvarghese - Please edit your question to show us what you actually want to see. Your descriptions are confusing.

Comment: so this is the csv file right:['Time', 'Date', 'Color  ', 'Name']
    ['1pm', '01-01-99', 'blue', 'jack']
    ['2pm', '02-02-99', 'green', 'kevin']
    ['3pm', '03-03-99', 'yellow', 'phil']
    ['4pm', '04-04-99', 'white', 'alice']
['5pm', '05-05-99', 'black', 'bob'] I want to read a line for example if said 4pm , i would want python to read across the 4pm line so the output would be something like:    ['4pm', '04-04-99', 'white', 'alice']

Comment: @albinvarghese please check with the updated code! Now, it'll print row by row. :)

Comment: thank you @Sree Harissh it does print rows(four of them) but is it possible to print just  one row?

Comment: @albinvarghese I have coded it such that if you enter the time, you're returned with the row. If you dont want the output separated by comma, replace the line " print ', '.join(row) " with " print row ". Is this what you're looking for, sir?

Comment: Thanks a lot @Sree Harissh , it does work but the raw_input part does not

Comment: @albinvarghese Use input instead of raw_input! :)